# Background wont change back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this video background when you first load the page up and then there's a button you click that overlays what's visible and puts a div that's the pages height, when you hide the div afterwards the video that I had is gone and a white background is present instead, why's that? thanks for help.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var yellowclicks = 0;
$('.x').hide();
$('.yellow-text-bg').hide();
$('.round-button-circle-x').hide();
$('.round-button-circle').click(function(){
    $('.round-button').css('margin-top','5%');
    $('#logo').fadeOut(80);
    $('.hiderow').hide();
    $('.round-button-circle').hide();
    $('.yellow-text-bg').delay(80).fadeIn(500);
    $('.round-button-circle-x').delay(80).fadeIn(500);
    yellowclicks =+1;
    $('.intro').hide();
});
$('.arrow').click(function(){
    $('.yellow-text-bg').fadeOut(400);
    $('#logo').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    $('.round-button-circle').delay(500).fadeIn(500).css('margin-top','10%');
});
```

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle.

Comment: Please, show us your html and css as well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/px60zngm/
It goes back to the body's background and the video's gone.

Comment: oh you need to click on the yellow circle to see it